# How come I can't develop on android with Java 7 in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, java-7

When I try to build Android project in eclipse with Java SDK set to 1.7, I get following error:

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

I understand, that setting the SDK to 1.6 works (it's all over the stack overflow), but here is my question: How come, that I am able to develop and deploy android application with usage of JDK 1.7 via IntelliJ Idea IDEA?

I am able to use multiple catch block, diamond operators, build it and run it on virtual and real Android devices with no problem. So how come, that Eclipse (and all the community) tries to tell me, that I need to use Java 1.6?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can't. What is yout reason to want it?

Comment: mostly the language constructs to make code more readable. thought that java 7 being out quite a long, it would be supported completely.

Comment: what exactly do you like in java 7? i actually know only 2 features:switch on strings and multiple exception catches. what else?

Comment: as I told: multiple catch block, diamond operator, new IO and concurrent package has received some improvements. Maybe it's not a killing change, but the language is improving and so should we, stucking at Java 6 if something better is available should not be something recommended or good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not officially support Java 7. Some features of Java 7 might compile to bytecode that the dalvik VM will understand, but it can't be guaranteed.